# Implement user activity logger in old application?

Tags: c++, logging, mfc, user-activity

How to go about implementing a user activity logger in MFC application.To get to know what are all the features are used most in an existing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [windows procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k57wfbs%28VS.80%29.aspx) of your application window:

```
class CMyMainWindow {
    void LogUsageData(UINT message);
    virtual LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
          LogData(message);
          return CWnd::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam); // route message to message map
     }
}
```

Note that the task is not so trivial: `LogUsageData` should discard most messages, focusing only on the ones defined in the [message map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1%28VS.80%29.aspx).
However, this should be a good place to start.